# check if 2 arrays have a matching string

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have 2 arrays:

`listOfPhotos` which ties into

```
@interface CactusQueuePhotos : NSObject
 @property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *ID, *QUEUEID, *IMAGEURL;
-(void)updateEntry;
-(void)createEntry;
@end
```

and  `listOfTasks` which ties to

```
@interface CactusQueue : NSObject
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *QDESCRIPTION, *LONGDESCRIPTION, *PRIORITY, *TAGS, *STATUS, *CATEGORY, *PRIMARYASSIGN, *LUPDATEREASON;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *ID, *ESTIMATEDHOURS1, *ESTIMATEDHOURS2, *PREREQUISITE, *ACTHOURS;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *CREATEDATE, *ASSIGNDATE, *DUEDATE, *STARTDATE, *COMPDATE, *LASTUPDATE;
@end
```

so `listOfTasks` is a list of tasks. and `listOfPhotos` are optional photos that are relevant to said task (based on ID).

on my tableView, I want to either show/hide and image based on whether `listOfPhotos` QUEUEID matches any of the ID's in `listOfTasks`

I've tried

```
if ([[listOfPhotos valueForKey:@"QUEUEID"] containsString:que.ID])
```

which resulted in a crash

> 2016-02-09 12:37:34.828 CactusQueue[2114:160258] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArray0 containsString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x135e000a0'

i can't use `containsObjects` objects because `CactusQueue` and `CactusQueuePhotos` aren't the same object

any help is appreciated

Comment: Try `containsObject:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That exception was thrown because NSArray class does not have a containsString selector. Instead you need to use "containsObject" selector.
Here is an example:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableStringArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[mutableStringArray addObject:@"Apple"];
[mutableStringArray addObject:@"Bacon"];
[mutableStringArray addObject:@"Cone"];

NSArray *stringArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableStringArray];

if ([stringArray containsObject:@"Apple"])
{
    NSLog(@"Apple was found!");
}
```